# I can't access the props of my objects (Angular)?

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I have this variable in my environment.ts:

```
featureToggle: {"feature1": true, "feature2: false}
```

In a service of mine, I want to give these values to a component with a getAll-method, just like:

```
getAll() {
    return environment.featureToggle;
}
```

In a component I'm having an array and call the servicemethod in my ngOnInit, where I assign the values to my array. Through *ngFor im iterating through the array.
Then I get an ERROR NG0901 IterableDiffers.find.

Yes, it might be, because it is an Object Array, so I would have to convert it in my service first to a normal Array, or assign the values to an interface to work with it?

like

```
interface FeatureInterface {
feature: string,
isActive: boolean;
}
```

But I can't even .map through my environments variable nor does forEach work. I also tried Object.keys(environment.featureToggle). Is there any way to access and iterate my properties in my environment.ts and work with them in any component?

Component:

```
features: FeatureInterface[] = []; 

ngOnInit(): void {
this.features = this.featureToggleService.getAllFeatures()
```

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of features">
{{item.feature}}
...
```

Comment: can you please paste the code, it helps to understand the problem

Comment: Does the edit help? What exactly do you need?

Comment: yes it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out!

```
let featureToggle = { "feature1": true, "feature2": false, "feature3": true};
const result = Object.entries(featureToggle).filter((e) => e[1]).map((i) => i[0]);
console.log(result);
```

UPDATE 1:

Based on the requirement(as mentioned in the comments), try this:

```
let featureToggle = { "feature1": true, "feature2": false, "feature3": true };
const result = Object.entries(featureToggle).map((i) => {
   return {
      feature: i[0],
      isAvailable: i[1]
   }
});
console.log(result);

[ { feature: 'feature1', isAvailable: true },
  { feature: 'feature2', isAvailable: false },
  { feature: 'feature3', isAvailable: true } ]
```

Comment: The result will be ['feature1', 'feature2'].

Comment: So then I can go through the result variable with *ngFor, right?
But what about the assigned boolean values? Like "feature1": true?
And btw my result is just ["feature1"], not more

Comment: thats what you want right?

Comment: regarding the assigned Boolean values, we already filtered out the available features, so why you still need it?

Comment: Because I want to to loop through all Objects ({"feature1": true, "feature2: false}) and then I want to display them in my html like this <div *ngFor="let item of result"> {{item.feature}} {{item.isActive}}. Just like my FeatureInterface looks like, I want to access the values f.e. "feature1" and "true" and display them. I hope I made my point clear now :D

Comment: You got it! I will remember you and Object.entries :D
Thanks!